Efficient sorting of large arrays with complex objects
I am currently working with a large dataset containing over 100,000 records. Each record is an object with multiple fields, including city, state, country (which may be nested), and other attributes like rating and type. I need to sort this array based on various parameters dynamically passed to the sorting function.
I have tried conventional sorting algorithms, but the best complexity I've achieved is O(nlogn). I am looking for a sorting method that could potentially improve on this, aiming for constant complexity or better scalability given the size and complexity of the data.
{
  "city": "Surat",
  "state": "Gujarat",
  "country": {"name": "India", "code": "IN"},
  "rating": 4.5,
  "type": "city"
},
{
  "state": "Gujarat",
  "country": {"name": "India", "code": "IN"},
  "rating": 4.8,
  "type": "state"
},
{
  "country": {"name": "India", "code": "IN"},
  "rating": 4.0,
  "type": "country"
}


"aiming for constant complexity" in a sorting algorithm?! Even radix/counting sort (and others in the same vein) don't achieve this. And they are more efficient than quicksort only because they are specialised. Quicksort being (as the name suggests) quite a good sorting algorithm being O(n * log n) on average.

it's not clear how you want to sort nested data, pls give exact input and output

The best complexity for a sort using comparisons is O(n log n). This is proven so you cannot overpass this limit. The only way to reduce the complexity is not to use comparisons. This is possible with a radix sort (as mentioned by VLAZ). Radix sort has a complexity of O(n). This is optimal since the input needs to be read. Regarding your specific use-case and details, it might be possible to do better but without them, this is not possible.

Note that the complexity is not directly related to speed. You can significantly improve the speed of a code without changing its complexity. Sometime algorithms with a worst complexity are faster (eg. naive matrix multiplication vs Strassen vs Copersmith-Vinograd: the latest algorithms are generally not used in the fastest libraries even though it has a better complexity, especially the last one which is a galactic algorithm).

Last but not least, performance is often dependent of the target language and the input data structure which are not provided... Please provide critical informations required to answer the question. Otherwise answerers will certainly make wrong assumptions/guesses (eg. picking the language they want).

I think to handle this you could:

Index your data with normalizing the fields into dictionaries, use an integer key to link the data with the dictionaries
Sort the dictionaries and make mapping between dictionary keys and their sorted indices, you can even use the sorted indices as keys.
Now you use any fast integer sorting algorithm to sort data with the help of the sorted dictionary indices/keys.

Btw for example in JS there's a library that does exactly this:
https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter
I believe there're more libraries in different languages that do exactly that (mimicking a relational db in memory)

Performance improvements assuming C | C++: instead of sorting records, sort an array of pointers to records, and use multi-threading with a merge sort. For K threads, split the array of pointers into K parts, and use K threads to sort the K parts. Then use K/2 threads to merge the K parts into K/2 parts, then K/4 threads to merge those parts, and finally a single thread to merge the final two parts. The compare should be handled by a pointer to function. An example of this is gnu sort, which defaults to 16 threads during it's initial in memory sort, which is all you may need. For large files, a memory sort is used to create a sorted chunk of data which is written to file. Once all the chunks are created, then the chunks are merged with a single thread, defaulting to a 16 way merge, but with SSD or NVMe SSD, a 2 or 4 way merge may be better.
